# javaxt.io.Image doubles in size when using saveAs()

Tags: java, image, jpeg

In an application, I need to use `javaxt.io.Image` to rotate the image and then save it into a new file. This is the code:

```
Image image = new Image(input);
image.rotate();
image.saveAs(output);
```

While the image does lose the EXIF rotation, which is the reason I needed this functionality, the image almost doubles in size. `input.jpg` is at `2.8MB`, while `output.jpg` becomes `4.3MB`. I couldn't find a parameter or function for compression in `javaxt.io.Image`.

Did I miss a step or is this behaviour wanted by the library? What would be the most efficient way to re-reduce the size?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [documentation for that library](http://www.javaxt.com/documentation/?jar=javaxt-core&package=javaxt.io&class=Image)? There seems to be a `setOutputQuality(...)` method on `Image`.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I did have a look at it, but I'll be honest, I was too fixated on the word "compression" and completely missed this function while going over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas commented, I missed the function `setOutputQuality(float quality)` in the [library documentation](http://www.javaxt.com/documentation/?jar=javaxt-core&package=javaxt.io&class=Image). Using that enables you to compress your images.